# How to compare 2 dynamic values in ngIf

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular,
trying to compare 2 property values of a Json in ngIf,

I have Address object with following properties Line1, Line2, City, County, Zip code, Country

I want to show County value on the UI, If County not equal to City,

I am using Angular 7

Example Address 1 on the database:

- Line1: abc123
- Line2: xyz
- City: London
- County: London
- Country: UK

Since County value is equal to City values 
On the UI I want to Show:

- abc123, xyz, London, UK

Example Address 2 on the database:

- Line1: asdf456
- Line2: lkj
- City: London
- County: qwerty
- Country: UK

Since County value is not equal to City values 
On the UI I want to Show:

- asdf456, lkj, London, qwerty, UK

so trying below code but it is not working.

`<div *ngIf="address.city == address.county">{{address.county}}</div>`

Tried with single quotes

`<div *ngIf="'address.city' == 'address.county'">{{address.county}}</div>`

and three equals '==='

`<div *ngIf="address.city === address.county">{{address.county}}</div>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This alone is not enough to tell what's wrong. The first and third solutions you provided should work provided `address` is defined correctly. The second solution, on the other hand, is just two different strings compared to each other which will always equal `false`.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to show the county when it _is_ the same as the city. Try the `!==` operator instead: `<div *ngIf="address.city !== address.county">{{address.county}}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

If it is dynamic like Observable etc:

```
<div *ngIf="address$ | async as address">
    <div *ngIf="address.city  == address.county">{{address.county}}</div>
</div>
```

`| async` Is an pipe for dynamic values Observables and Promises. Small tip try to not use this pipe in *ngFor loop.